# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can i solve this error `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

I am trying to display specific JSON content from a ticker link, but unfortunately couldn't get it to work, as the error keep popping.

**HTML**

```
  <input id="currency1" type="text">
  <span>Currency1</span>
  <input id="currency2" type="text">
  <span>Currency2</span>
  <div>
  <button type="button" onclick="refreshPrice()">
  Refresh Price
  </button>
  <span id="lastPrice"></span>
  </div>
```

**JSON Response from the Ticker Link**

```
{"ticker":{"high":"16985100","low":"16730900","last":"16879000"}}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var lastPrice;
function refreshPrice() { 
$lastPrice = $('#lastPrice'); 
$lastPrice.html("");
$.get("https://example.com") //Ticker link
.then(function (data) {
  lastPrice = JSON.parse(data).ticker.last - 100000;
  lastPrice.html(lastPrice);
});
}

refreshPrice();
$('#currency2').keyup(function() {
currency2Val = parseFloat($(this).val());
if (currency2Val) {
 currency1Val = currency2Val * lastPrice;
  $('#currency1').val(parseInt(currency1Val));
}
else {
  $('#currency1').val("");
}
});

$('#currency1').keyup(function() {
currency1Val = parseInt($(this).val());
if (currency1Val) {
currency2Val = currency1Val / lastPrice;
  $('#currency2').val(currency2Val.toFixed(8));
}
else {
  $('#currency2').val("");
}
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: your response is probably HTML rather than JSON ... or it's already been parsed, and you're trying to parse an object! ... try `lastPrice = data.ticker.last - 100000;`

Comment: also `lastPrice.html(lastPrice);` doesn't make sense if `lastPrice` is a `Number` (which it surely will be) - I think you meant `$lastPrice.html(lastPrice);`

Comment: That's correct, and you are right regarding the `$lastPrice.html(lastPrice)`, that solved the error message. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ticker responds with the correct `Content-Type` header, jQuery will **already** have parsed the response for you. So remove the `JSON.parse`:

```
$.get("https://example.com") //Ticker link
.then(function (data) {
  lastPrice = data.ticker.last - 100000;
  $lastPrice.html(lastPrice);
});
```

*(I've also included a fix there for [the issue Jaromanda X pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594980/json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-2-of-the-json-data-html/42595006#comment72321132_42594980), using `lastPrice` rather than `$lastPrice`.)*

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> `dataType` (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> Type: String
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. **If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object**, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove JSON.parse,

```
var lastPrice;
function refreshPrice() { 
$lastPrice = $('#lastPrice'); 
$lastPrice.html("");
$.get("https://example.com") //Ticker link
.then(function (data) {
  debugger;
  lastPrice = data.ticker.last - 100000;
  lastPrice.html(lastPrice);
});
}
```

Put a debugger as well, to see what is your response.

Answer (score 0):

Response is already in JSON format, you shouldn't be passing it through JSON.parse, as JSON.parse expects input to be a stringify JSON

Try this :

```
   lastPrice = data.ticker.last - 100000;
```